# Why is $E[X^{2}] \ge E[X]^{2}$?

Tags: probability, statistics, summation, proof-explanation, expected-value

I was trying to prove that $E[X^{2}] \ge E[X]^{2} \quad \mathbf{(0)}$.

Where $E[X]$ is the expected value of a random variable, $X$, i.e., $E[X] = \sum_{x}x p_{X}(x)$

Now, I'm not asking how to prove $\mathbf{(0)}$, I know the method using variance etc. I'm asking is why is $\mathbf{(3)}$ true? (In other words, how to prove this continuing from $\mathbf{(3)}$.

$$\begin{align*}
E[X]^{2} \qquad & \longleftrightarrow \qquad ( \ \sum_{x}x \ p_{X}(x) \ )^{2} \\
& \longleftrightarrow \qquad ( \ x_{1} \ p_{X}(x_{1}) + x_{2} \ p_{X}(x_{2}) + \dots + x_{n} \ p_{X}(x_{n}) \ )^{2} \\
& \longleftrightarrow \qquad \ x_{1}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{1})^{2} + x_{2}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{2})^{2} + \dots + x_{n}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{n})^{2} + \dots + 2( \ x_{i}x_{j} \ p_{X}(x_{i}) \ p_{X}(x_{j}) ) + \dots \quad \mathbf{(1)} \\ 
\textrm{And likewise, } \\\\
E[X^{2}] \qquad & \longleftrightarrow \qquad \sum_{x}x^{2} \ p_{X}(x) \\
& \longleftrightarrow \qquad x_{1}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{1}) + x_{2}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{2})+ \dots + x_{n}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{n}) \quad \mathbf{(2)}\\
\textrm{Now, why is:  } \\
\end{align*} \\
x_{1}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{1}) + x_{2}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{2})+ \dots + x_{n}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{n}) \ge \ x_{1}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{1})^{2} + x_{2}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{2})^{2} + \dots + x_{n}^{2} \ p_{X}(x_{n})^{2} + \dots + 2( \ x_{i}x_{j} \ p_{X}(x_{i}) \ p_{X}(x_{j}) ) + \dots \qquad \mathbf{(3)}\\
$$
$ \ \ \quad$ i.e., why is, $\mathbf{(1)} \ge \mathbf{(2)}$

Comment: Apply Jensen's inequality to $f(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract $x_1^2\ p_X(x_1)^2 + \cdots + x_n^2\ p_X(x_n)^2$ from both sides and note that
$$x_i^2\ p_X(x_i) - x_i^2\ p_X(x_i)^2 = x_i^2\ p_X(x_i)\ (1-p_X(x_i)) = x_i^2\ p_X(x_i)\ \sum_{j\ :\ j\neq i}p_X(x_j) = \sum_{j \ : \ j\neq i}x_i^2\ p_X(x_i)\ p_X(x_j)$$

The resulting inequality you want to show is
$$\sum_{(i,j)\ : \ i < j} (x_i^2+x_j^2)\ p_X(x_i)\ p_X(x_j) \geq \sum_{(i,j)\ : \ i < j} 2x_ix_j\ p_X(x_i)\ p_X(x_j)$$
which follows, since $p_X(x_i)\ p_X(x_j) \geq 0$, from $x_i^2 + x_j^2 \geq 2x_ix_j$, or equivalently, $$x_i^2 + x_j^2 - 2x_ix_j = (x_i-x_j)^2 \geq 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 5):

Note that expanding and simplifying the definition of variance gives

$$E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2.$$

Conclude by recognizing that for real-valued random variable $X$, the LHS is the mean of $(X-E[X])^2\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $p_X(x_j)\leq 1$, so that $p_X(x_j)\geq p_X(x_j)^2$ for every $j$. In fact, the inequality for (3) is strict if and only if $X$ is not a constant random variable.

Comment: But we're also adding $2(x_{i}x_{j} \ p_{X}(x_{i}) \ p_{X}(x_{j}))$'s, and those could be greater than zero.

Comment: @IbrahimHasaan Oops sorry, missed that part. You should be able to apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality here.